# ¿Por que el css de React JS se comparten en todos los componentes?

Tags: css, reactjs

Hay algo que no estoy entendiendo muy bien y es el por que los css impactan en todos los componentes pese a que cada componente tiene un css unico.
Por ejemplo:
El componente "Componente1.jsx" tiene un css llamado "Componente1.css" lo mismo sucede con el proximo componente "Componente2.jsx" y "Componente2.css"... Sucede que si yo modifico algo en el Componente2.css por alguna razon impacta en el "Componente1.jxs" por lo tanto no logro comprender el funcionamiento de componentes de React Js.
¿Podrian explicarme como evitar esto?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @Mankusa. Podrias por favor compartir el codigo de los .jsx asi entender que estas haciendo mal, y ver como importas los .css

Comment: Deberias mostrar el codigo porque de hecho en la manera en la que formulas la pregunta te diria que es imposible que el css se comparta, a menos que estes importando los estilos de componete1.css en componente2.jsx y llamando a las etiquetas igual que en el componente1.jsx
Quiza has importado mas de la cuenta o no veas que parte de un elemento en en realidad pertenece a otro.